# How to create for my android app a tutorial for user on first installation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, carousel

i want to create a basic tutorial, introduction, for my android app. There are many apps that have this feature, like yahoo news digest, flickr, google drive, play music, etc.

There is an example:

[image]

I want to do something like this, but in 7 simple steps. I am newbie and i have no idea to begin with.

Someone?

Comment: use SharedPreference to save tutorial viewed value this way you can track if users is viewing app first time

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this library available on github. https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro 
This is specifically designed for making a cool introduction to your android application